# How to get the parent element type only for elements that have title attributes?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve the following to request for only anchor elements with title attributes, to tell me what their parent elements are:

```
var mtype =  $(".my-selectors").find("a").prop("title").parent().prop('nodeName');
console.log(mtype);
```

> index.htm:563 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).prop(...).parent is
>   not a function

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `prop("title")` returns the content of that attribute, a string value. You are not dealing with a jQuery object here any more at that point, and therefor your attempt to call the `parent` method fails - the String object does not have such a method.

Comment: Thank you so much for that clarification!  So what do developers do when they want to filter anchor links only with titles, and still keep jQuery alive??

Comment: In situations where a simple CSS selector solution as suggested by SpYk3HH was not available, at the most basic you would do a loop over all links `$(".my-selectors a").each(...)`, and in there check the attribute/property in question, and proceed from there with doing whatever with/to the element's parent ... Edit: SpYk3HH has edited their answer in that regard in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for that knowledge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a simple [**has attribute selector**](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

```
var mtype = $('.my-selectors a[title]').parent().prop('nodeName')
```

Although, keep in mind, as is, this will only grab nodeName property for the parent of the FIRST one it finds.

A more specific, and possibly better move might be:

```
$('.my-selectors a[title]').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).parent().length) { // should always have be true, but ...
        var mtype = $(this).parent().prop('nodeName');
    //  could also be defined with "= this.parentNode.nodeName;"
        console.log(mtype);
        /*  doWork  */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('a[title]').each(function() { console.log(this.parentNode.nodeName) })`